# Is it possible to find this volume with one integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, bounds-of-integration

Find the volume of the solid that lies within the sphere $^2+^2+^2=81$, above the  plane, and outside the cone $=5\sqrt{^2+^2})$.

My difficulties are that having it be outside the cone, you must also have a way to find the volume of the tip of the sphere over the cone. I tried to represent the tip by looking at the xz plane shown in the picture below. I see no way to express this spherically or cylindrically. My best bet is to calculate the hemisphere volume by $\frac43\pi r^3$ and then subtract the cone volume from that which is found rather easily cylindrically.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think your strategy is good ("My best bet is to calculate the hemisphere volume by $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ and then subtract the cone volume from that which is found rather easily cylindrically.")

Comment: Technically your sketch is incorrect. You shouldn't be including any region "above" the cone like you do now. Remember, the cone does not have a finite height, it extends infinitely upwards.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ahh, that makes great sense. Thank you!

Comment: You can also treat the desired region as a solid of revolution.

Comment: @user170231 that is exactly what cylindrical coordinates is.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Right, but many calculus students learn about solids of revolution before ever hearing about different coordinate systems.

Comment: @user170231 in context, OP is a multivariable calculus student. Solids of revolution won't help if they are asked to compute an integral with an integrand without rotational symmetry instead of a volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do this with one integral directly (as opposed to an indirect symmetry argument, but I don't recommend those because it is fair question to ask to set up and do the integrals over the same region but with an integrand that does not share that symmetry).

Cylindrical ($dr$ first):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\frac{45}{\sqrt{26}}} \int_{\frac{z}{5}}^{\sqrt{81-z^2}} rdrdzd\theta$$

Spherical ($d\rho$ first):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\cot^{-1}(5)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^9 \rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

Spherical ($d\phi$ first):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}  \int_0^9 \int_{\cot^{-1}(5)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \rho^2\sin\phi d\phi d\rho d\theta$$

which follows from Fubini's theorem in hindsight, but it is important to consider the last integration order since most people don't when it could in certain situations make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cross section of the solid in the plane $y=0$, so that in your picture, the axes drawn are the $x$- and $z$-axes.

In this plane, when $x\ge0$, the equation of the cone reduces to $z=5\sqrt{x^2}=5x\implies x=\frac z5$, and the equation of the hemisphere reduces to $z^2+x^2=81\implies x=\sqrt{81-z^2}$.

Then the volume of the solid is given by

$$\pi\int_0^{45/\sqrt{26}}\left(\left(\sqrt{81-z^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac z5\right)^2\right)\,\mathrm dz=\pi\int_0^{45/\sqrt{26}}\left(81-\frac{26}{25}z^2\right)\,\mathrm dz=\boxed{1215\sqrt{\frac2{13}}\,\pi}$$